# supervisord: Can you run two programs with the same name but on a different command path?

Tags: supervisord

When I create two files:

***horizon-staging.conf***

```
[program:horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /var/www/staging/current/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
redirect_stderr=true
```

***horizon-production.conf***

```
[program:horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /var/www/production/current/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
redirect_stderr=true
```

and fire the command `sudo supervisorctl start horizon`. Does it run both programs? (Side question, can I put this also in one conf file?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

The program's name isn't strictly related to the application's name. The correct path would be to create both an horizon-staging and an horizon-production like such:

```
[program:horizon-staging]
process_name=horizon
command=php /var/www/staging/current/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
redirect_stderr=true

[program:horizon-production]
process_name=horizon
command=php /var/www/production/current/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
redirect_stderr=true
```

So it'd have both entrypoint options.

And yes, you can declare two different programs inside the same conf.